# scrapy proxy getting scrapy.http.response.Response has no attribute 'encoding'

Tags: proxy, scrapy

I'm now using Scrapy to crawl one site through a http proxy. I followed the instructions of http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/04/07/using-scrapy-with-proxies/ . But when I run my spider, I got the following error:

**ERROR: Error downloading http://xxx.xxx.xxx : Not a gizpped file.**

Then I added the following statement in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES of setting.py:

**'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': None**

After this, the debug info indicated me that I crawled the web page correctly but when processing the page, I got the following error:

**'Response' object has no attribute 'encoding'**

Please give me some tips how to sovle this problem. Thanks in advance for all.

Comment: Can you include the code of your spider; or at least the part where it goes wrong?

Comment: @SjaakTrekhaak Sorry I've found what's wrong. It was caused by the http proxy. Sometimes the html source file returned by the http proxy was gzipped and in this situation, tthe respones could not be parsed by HtmlXPathSelector in Scrapy. Sometimes the html source file returned was not gzipped and the respone could be parsed by HtmlPathSelctor. After modifying some arguments in the http proxy, it's ok. Thank you anyway :)